What is correct way to declare timestamp "2024-09-24T07:26:51.198+00:00" in OpenAPI 3.0?
What is correct way to declare timestamp "2024-09-24T07:26:51.198+00:00" in an OpenAPI 3.0 spec?
I think the following should work, but it is not working.
type: object
properties:
  responseDate:
    type: string
    format: date-time
    description: Date at which this response was sent.


Are you using OpenAPI 3.0 or 2.0?

Your definition is correct. How exactly is it not working? What tool do you use, what exactly are you doing, what result do you expect and what result do you see instead?

As @Helen has mentioned above, your definition is correct. This definition holds true for values like "2024-09-24T07:26:51.198+05:30", "2024-09-24T07:26:51.198-04:00", "2024-09-24T07:26:51.198+00:00" etc. Note that you can write "2024-09-24T07:26:51.198+00:00" also as "2024-09-24T07:26:51.198Z".

my bad, it is working fine in case of request. But how to get the current time in the same format in response. Currently I am trying  validateBankAccountResponse.setInquiryTimestamp(OffsetDateTime.now());
